# sharedPreferences with boolean in iconButton flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to save boolean values to my iconButton in flutter. But when I close and open the application again, it doesn't come with the last value.
my Code is here:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isPressed = true;
  var state = FlutterVpnState.disconnected;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initSharedPreferences();
    FlutterVpn.prepare();
    FlutterVpn.onStateChanged.listen((s) => setState(() => state = s));
  }

  void initSharedPreferences() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool? savedIsPressed = prefs.getBool('isPressed');
  }

  void saveBoolPreferences(String key, bool value) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setBool(key, value);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // some code here
              IconButton(onPressed: () async {
                  if (state == FlutterVpnState.disconnected) {
                    setState(() {
                      isPressed = true;
                    });
                    try {
                      await FlutterVpn.connectIkev2EAP(
                        server: dataAddress,
                        username: _usernameController.text,
                        password: _passwordController.text,
                      );
                      setState(() {
                        isPressed = false;
                      });
                    } catch (e) {
                      setState(() {
                        isPressed = false;
                      });
                    }
                  } else {
                    FlutterVpn.disconnect();
                    setState(() {
                      isPressed = true;
                    });
                  }
                  saveBoolPreferences('is_pressed', isPressed);
                },
                icon: state == FlutterVpnState.connecting || state == FlutterVpnState.disconnecting
                  ? LoadingAnimationWidget.inkDrop(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 100)
                  : state == FlutterVpnState.disconnected
                    ? Image.asset('assets/images/power-on.png')
                    : Image.asset('assets/images/power-off.png')
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? Thank you in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving bool with `is_pressed`

```dart
 saveBoolPreferences('is_pressed', isPressed);
```

But while fetching it, you are using different key `isPressed`.

```dart
 bool? savedIsPressed = prefs.getBool('isPressed');
```

You need to use the same key.

You can do

```dart
 bool? savedIsPressed = prefs.getBool('is_pressed');
```

Next to fetch from sharedPref, you can follow this sample pattern.

```dart
Future<bool> getButtonState() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  bool? savedIsPressed = prefs.getBool('isPressed');
  return savedIsPressed ?? false;
}
```

Now create a state future(for StatefulWidget) variable

```dart
  late final buttonStateFuture = getButtonState();
```

Now using futureBuilder with the future.

```dart
 FutureBuilder<bool>(
    future: buttonStateFuture,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      bool isPressed = snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data == true;
      return IconButton(
          onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(isPressed ? Icons.done : Icons.close));
    },
  )
```

Find more about [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

Comment: I have change with the same key, but the iconButton still can't save the last state

Comment: You can fetch it from future while, futureBuilder will be better